# How does the offline mode works in Magestore and XPOS?

Tags: pos

It's a big pleasure to "virtually" meet you!

Anybody of you have details regarding how Magestore or XPOS work in offline mode?
Which are the functionalities available?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: When offline mode is enabled in configuration, a database containing products and customers is stored locally on your PC in a Web storage. It is continuously updated to make sure that the data are always up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

X-POS has been stopped by its developer and replaced by the new one called [ConnectPOS](https://www.connectpos.com). When the app detects that you lost Internet connection, it will switch automatically to Offline Mode and pop up a notification on the screen, you don't have to do anything. When the Internet is back, it turns off Offline Mode and starts synchronizing offline orders to Magento. For a full list of ConnectPOS functionalities, I recommend you check out their Features page or [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/sm-module-retail.html) page.

[image]